# Physics2D.Raycast Works On Some Objects But Doesn't Work On Others

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting, collider

So I'm trying to make a clone of Super Mario Bros for practice. I was creating the World 1-1. Everything was working great: I could move, enemies can move and be killed, and blocks can be interacted just like expected. But at this time I was using colliders and they were causing some problems here and there, also I couldn't find a way to make the enemies move in the opposite direction when they are faced with a collider. So I looked at some other people and saw that they were using raycasting. Then decided to try it myself. There was no problem on the enemy script.

**Enemy Script**

```
private void RayCast()
{
    // Getting the max distance by using the size of the collider and creating the ray itself
    float rayMaxDistance = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.size.x/2;
    Ray2D ray = new Ray2D(transform.position, Vector2.right);
    
    // This way ray will be casted in the direction the enemy goes.
    if (rb.velocity.x > 0)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, rayMaxDistance);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag != "Player")
            {
                // Moving in the opposite direction
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rb.AddForce(-movementVector, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
        //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.red);
        
    }
    // This way ray will be casted in the direction the enemy goes.
    else if (rb.velocity.x < 0)
    {
        ray.direction = Vector3.left;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, rayMaxDistance);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag != "Player")
            {
                // Moving in the opposite direction
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rb.AddForce(movementVector, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
        //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.red);
```

It worked as intended, but when I tried to use it on Mario, it didn't work somehow.

**The part in character script. (It's not completed because it doesn't even work now)**

```
private void ActivateLuckyBlock()
{
    float maxRayDistance = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.size.y/2;
    Ray2D ray = new Ray2D(transform.position, Vector2.up);

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, maxRayDistance);

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("There is something");  
    }
}
```

- This code outputs "There is something" even if there is nothing above the player. So it never returns null, that should mean it hits something every time right?
- I thought that maybe it was somehow colliding with the player's collider, but it doesn't happen with the enemy even though they are the same.
- I've tested multiple distances including infinite.
- Also checked if there was anything in the scene that I didn't see in the first place, but couldn't find it.
- I've tried calling the method on both Update and FixedUpdate; neither of them worked as intended.
- Ray origin and direction also works while testing with Debug.DrawRay().

I've been looking through the internet for any kind of answer, but couldn't find anything about it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's not even a full implementation, just wanted to test. Still, it doesn't work. Please help me before I go insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The ray origin should be the centre of the bounds** and try to add a little extra space for maxRayDistance, (bounds.extents is equal to bounds.size/2:[documentation for bounds.extent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-extents.html))

```
float maxRayDistance = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.extents.y + 0.001f;
Ray2D ray = new Ray2D(GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.center, Vector2.up);
```

Try changing the Debug.Log, this will allow you to know what the name of the object the ray cast is hitting:

```
Debug.Log("Raycast hit:" + hit.collider.name);
```

If you're still having issues, make a public layerMask variable, create and add a layer for the object you want to ray cast at:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, maxRayDistance, layerMask);
```

Call the function through the Update or Fixed Update:

It should look something like this:

```
public LayerMask luckyBlockMask;
    void Update()
    {
        ActivateLuckyBlock();
    }
    private void ActivateLuckyBlock()
    {
        float maxRayDistance = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.extents.y + 0.1f;
        Ray2D ray = new Ray2D(GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.center, Vector2.up);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, maxRayDistance,
        luckyBlockMask);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Raycast hit:" + hit.collider.name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used the hit.collider.name and realized that it was hitting itself. Then I did what you did exactly, and now it's not recognizing itself, but also it's not doing anything. I changed all of my blocks' layers to a layer called "blocks" and got that layer with GetMask method, but somehow I can't get to make it work. It doesn't recognize the blocks. They have a box collider 2d and a rigidbody 2d. The rigidbody was set to static, so I though that might be the problem, but even when I changed it to kinematic or dynamic, it still doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Nevermind, now I tried Mathf.Infinity again and it worked. Then I changed the value from 0.001f to 0.1f and now it's working. Thanks!